# Angular Component is using ng-template from its child

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-template

i have the following problem:

In my html i have the following code:

```
<form-section>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <form-section>
        <ng-template test-template>
            TEST
        </ng-template>
    </form-section>
</form-section>
```

And the output is something like this:

```
Hello TEST
TEST
```

but it should look like this:

```
Hello
TEST
```

In my `form-section-component.html` i have the following structure:

```
<div *ngIf="actionTemplate">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="actionTemplate"></ng-template>
</div>
```

In my `form-section-component.ts`:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateDirective, { read: TemplateRef, static: false }) actionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

So here to the template should only be displayed when it exists. But somehow my parent component displays the template as well. Even it has no template.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.html` file you have nested `<form-section>` tags. Am I correct?
Inside `<form-section>` there is already one `ng-template`.

[image]

Btw, if you want to insert some content between component tags you should use `ng-content`.
https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Comment: Yes this is just a simplified example. I have a nested `<form-section>` component.  the `ng-template` is applied to both components. it should only be applied to the child component